# Forem gem: how to link a forum to other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, rubygems

I have groups (`Group` model) in my app, which represent groups of people.
I want each group to have its own forum.

Should I just have the forum id in the `groups` table? It doesn't feel right. If I did it myself, the forum would have a polymorphic association to a "forumable" element (groups in this case, but I have other models that would need a forum).

Any opinions on what I should do? Modify the gem to fit my needs, or just have the forum_id in my models that need a forum? Or another solution maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the guy who started Forem (its the volunteers who did most of the hard work, though!), I think I can answer this question.

If you want only certain groups to have access to one and only one forum then you can put the `forum_id` field on the `groups` table and do it that way. What you can do then is override the `can_read_forem_forum?` method in your `User` model to perform a permission check for that user:

```
def can_read_forem_forum?(forum)
  groups.where(:forum_id => forum.id).any?
end
```

This is used in [Forem's ability model](https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/master/app/models/forem/ability.rb#L23) to determine whether or not a person can access a forum. What this method is going to do is that it will only return groups for that user that have link that specific forum. If there are any, then it's known that the user can access that forum.

Now if you're going the other route where a group may have access to many forums, well then you'd define a joins table between `groups` and `forem_forums` (called `forum_groups`) and define it as an association in your `Group` model like this:

```
has_many :forum_groups
has_many :forums, :through => :forum_groups, :class_name => "Forem::Forum"
```

You would need to also define a new model inside your application for this `forum_groups` association, it would be called `ForumGroup` and go a little like this:

```
class ForumGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum, :class_name => "Forem::Forum"
  belongs_to :group
end
```

We're doing it this way so you have an easy way to manage the associations between forums and groups. If you did `has_and_belongs_to_many`, it generally only provides a gigantic pain in the ass when you want to delete one specific record from that join table.

Now, with that all nicely set up, the method you want to define in your `User` model is this one:

```
def can_read_forem_forum?(forum)
  groups.joins(:forums).where("forem_forums.id = ?", forum.id).any?
end
```

Same thing, except this time we find all the groups that are linked to a specific forum through that association we set up earlier. This will do an `INNER JOIN` on the `forum_groups` table, and then another on the `forem_forums` table, getting the data required.

I hope this helps you, and thanks for using Forem!

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer! My groups are more like meetup groups, not the groups used by forums in general to manage permissions. So basically, I need a one to one relationship between groups and forums. One group will have one forum, so that they can chat about whatever. So I guess I should go with the first solution. But it just seems strange to have a group "belongs_to" forum.